# Why does using the unnamed package or smaller package names makes the Jar smaller?

Tags: java, java-me, package, naming, midp

I wasn't able to find much information about exactly why using shorter names on packages or using the unnamed package (default package) actually makes the jar size smaller.

I've read obfuscators strip unused classes and make the names of the remaining ones smaller and this reduces the jar size. And I've actually tried it my self and by using the unnamed package in one of my applications I got a 1.2% reduction in file size. But I couldn't find any trustworthy information on why this happens. I can only assume it is because of the overhead a long name introduces. Still I would appreciate any tips on how to justify this.

Initially I got the idea from this document: http://carfield.com.hk/document/java/articles/Efficient_MIDP_Programming.pdf

It really doesn't explain why though.

Comment: What are you looking for if not *"the overhead a long name introduces"* ?

Comment: Well, it's pretty simple, actually: all references to classes are done using their fully-qualified name (i.e. package+name). And although each class name will be stored only once per class file it is referenced it, having shorter names (i.e. less bytes of data) will add up over many classes. `x.a` is 3 bytes, whereas `com.mycompany.product.client.android.MyFancyViewComponent` is ... more (too lazy to count).

Comment: @dystroy I'm not sure where the overhead is being added.@JoachimSauer Ok thanks, so this com.mycompany.product.client.android.MyFancyViewComponent happens with every single object?

Answer (score 1):

Jar files are Zip files with another extension and a special (and optional) folder named META-INF. For each file or folder there is a header associated. As headers take some space of the jar you better keep less files in it, but if you already took it to the bare minimum then keep all those files in the root directory.

For MIDlet distribution the jar file must have the META-INF folder so, for best space usage, your jar files should have only this folder. Your MIDlet and all other classes should be on default package. The same with resource files, keep all of them at file root.

As seen in http://smallandadaptive.blogspot.com.br/2008/09/keep-it-flat.html